# Cast attribute to lowercase

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have an Eloquent model and would like to cast string attributes to be lowercase, but can't see from the docs whether this is possible?:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: There is [ample documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) about creating custom casts. Step one is `artisan make:cast` and then it's one line of code to lowercase something.

Comment: yeh was expecting something like 'string:lower' or smth, you know, laravel-style ;-)

Answer (score 1):

An accessor would be the best approach to this
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     */
    protected function firstName(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn (string $value) => Str::lower($value),
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT: For pre saving use a mutator:
Instead of the `Str::lower` being on the `get` place it on the `set`

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     */
    protected function firstName(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            set: fn (string $value) => Str::lower($value),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm thanks @jon-white similar but seems to be for *accessing* the attribute (as opposed to casting it, which is really intended for pre-saving purposes). Strange that this is not in the casting docs (might be good reason for it).

Comment: For pre-saving use mutators form the same documentation